# RegEx greedy quantifier not working correctly

Tags: regex

I made this little RegEx to find decimal number in a string but my quantifier does something that I can’t explain.

Here is my regular expression :

```
(?: *\d{1,3})*,\d{2}
```

And an example of what it is matching (with `**` highlights to indicate the match):

> **2000 1 142,94** 1  142,94

And what it should match :

> 2000 **1 142,94** 1 141,94

*The format for the group separator is a space, e.g. `1 000 000,00`*

The problem here, is that my *re* matches with the `2000` at the start of the example.

I tried to use a visualizer to verify my way of thinking but it seemed correct for me. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more on what to get matched and what not? a example will clear most of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression says zero or more spaces, followed by one to three digits, which obviously matches the initial 200. Then you allow a repetition with zero spaces and, for example, one more digit.  That's what "greedy" means; the regex engine will do its darndest to find a string which matches the pattern you gave it.

Apparently your real requirement is to find numbers with groups of three digits, is that correct?

```
(?:\d{1,3}( \d{3})*)?,\d{2}
```

This will require one to three digits, then zero or more groups with a space and three more digits, followed by the decimal comma and two decimal digits.

Your original attempt permitted `,12` so I have preserved that requirement; if you actually want to permit a number with optional decimals, perhaps instead go with

```
\d{1,3}( \d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I didn’t thought that my spacing quantifier would causes the engine to continue its search. Maybe I could have also tried to use a space delimiter after the numbers or used a word boundary ?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, but understanding how the engine will always skip something if it's optional if that will produce a match is the key thing. The second solution here is what I would regard as canonical and probably a duplicate of several existing similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear. I thought you want to extract decimal numbers from a string.

I used this regex to detect numbers with max three decimal. (eg. 123,234 or 123,23). And I also add both comma & dot point `(, & .)` as decimal separator.I put it inside group `()` to extract easily.

```
(\d{1,3}[,\.]\d{1,3})
```

Here's regex101 link that I tested - https://regex101.com/r/po6Rqr/1

Comment: Thank you and sorry. I didn’t specified the exact searched pattern. I will add it to my post.